# Disable Horizontal Scrolling to UITextView Programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextview, horizontal-scrolling

I'm looking for a way to disable horizontal scrolling of a UITextView programmatically, it was easy via the Interface Builder, but since I'm designing the view programmatically I can't find a way to do this, I've googled it as well but the most I got was this:

[How to stop the horizontal scrolling programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801126/how-to-stop-the-horizontal-scrolling-programmatically)

and it is not working.
Any hints?

```
self.textViewOpenedRect = CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 130);
self.textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: self.textViewOpenedRect];
self.textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5);
self.textView.delegate = self;
self.textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.textView.contentSize = CGSizeMake( self.textView.frame.size.height, self.textView.contentSize.height);

self.textView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = NO;
self.textView.bounces = NO;
```

UPDATE: apparently the problem is because of that line of code:

```
self.textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5);
```

wich I use to have a bit of space between the frame and the text. . .am I doing it properly?

Comment: You should post some code, just incase there is something you are doing wrong. Unless you haven't tried to implement what is on that link.

Comment: If you make an answer, then write it out as an answer, don't just amend your post and mark the wrong answer correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should help...
`UITextView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, so this is pretty easy to implement.

```
mytextView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(mytextView.frame.size.height,mytextView.contentSize.height);

mytextView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
```

Comment: did it before and the problem is still there, it still shows horizontal indicator and "moves a bit"... I really don't know why

Comment: read my update, by commenting that line the problem went away O_O

Comment: @i_mush: just in case you need horizontal insets, decrease your UITextView's contentSize.width accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a bit here, that "tiny bit of scrolling left and right" even after you disable horizontal scrolling is caused by the ContentInsets. The following disables that:

```
self.textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, 5, 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

With custom insets i found the best solution for me is to subclass the UITextView and then in the layoutSubviews call the following code.

```
-(void) layoutSubviews
{
    // always keep content offset at x = 0
    self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.contentOffset.y );
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This is great. The only thing that really worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: I really don't see how this is not accepted answer, since i's the only one that actually works. Thanks!