# UITextView how disable horizontal scrolling with content inset

Tags: ios, uitextview

I created UITextview programmatically and I need set some left margin in text. I do this like:

```
myTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

this working, but now I have horizontal scrolling.
I try set `contentSize` less than my text view frame (it equals 320 pt).

This

```
myTextView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(300.0, 39.0);
```

don't help.

I need to set left margin for text and only vertical scrolling.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In stead of contentInset, use textContainerInset (iOS 7.0+)

```
myTextView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

With custom insets i found the best solution for me is to subclass the UITextView and then in the layoutSubviews call the following code.

```
-(void) layoutSubviews
{
    // always keep content offset at x = 0
    self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.contentOffset.y );
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

Hope this helps someone. I also posted this answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/24027310/2661613