# Disable horizontal scrolling in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uiscrollview, uitextview

Hello: I'm building an app that supports iOS 6 and higher. I have a few `UITextView`s throughout the app, and I noticed that on iOS 6, the text views are able to be scrolled horizontally. On iOS 7, they can only be scrolled vertically. Is there a way to restrict scrolling so that it will only scroll vertically?

I've checked out some other similar questions, but I don't want to add a `UILabel` to a `UIScrollView`.

Any help is much appreciated!

**EDIT**

When using the following two lines (per the answers suggested), this still doesn't work when setting content insets. Anyone know how to fix this?

Attempt to disable scroll:

```
tView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(tView.frame.size.width, tView.contentSize.height);
tView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = FALSE;
```

Insets:

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
      tView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(kTextViewInsets, kTextViewInsets, kTextViewInsets, kTextViewInsets);
} else {
      tView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(kTextViewInsets, kTextViewInsets, kTextViewInsets, kTextViewInsets);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would subclass `UITextView` and override `setContentOffset`:

```
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset
{
    super.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, // Ignore the passed offset. Could also use self.contentOffset.x
                                      contentOffset.y);
}
```

Comment: Were you able to test this on iOS 6? I just realized Xcode 6 dropped the iOS 6 simulator...

Comment: Dropped on mine as well!

Comment: Hmm. Any idea how to run an app on the iOS 6 sim? The app that this question was about still supports it, and if your answer works I'd be glad to accept it and reward the bounty.

Comment: You'll have to install Xcode 5 again. You can safely rename it to keep both versions. https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode

Comment: Just installed Xcode 5 and 6.1 Sim. Doesn't appear to be working on 10.10 (simulator launches but refuses to load 6.1 even after a reset). Guess there isn't really a way to test this. This answer seems the most promising if I ever get it to work, though. Thanks!

Comment: You should also better stick to OS X 10.9.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
mytextView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(mytextView.frame.size.width,HEIGHT_YOU_WANT);

mytextView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
```

ALso take a look at [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657746/disable-horizontal-scrolling-to-uitextview-programmatically) may it help you.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Please take a look at my edit, this doesn't work when setting content insets.

Comment: I tried it, but I'm still not having any luck. I also tried hardcoding the values. Any ideas?